# Is there any java library for converting document from pdf to html?

Tags: java, html, pdf

Open source implementation will be preferred.

Comment: I would like to know a solution for this too. PDFBox is able to do so (http://java.dzone.com/articles/converting-pdf-html-using?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+javalobby%2Ffrontpage+%28Javalobby+%2F+Java+Zone%29), but in a very limited way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, it isn't an easy task, PDF formatting is much richer than HTML's one (plus you must extract images and link them, etc.).
Simple text extraction is much simpler (although not trivial...).
I see in the sidebar of your question a similar question: [Converting PDF to HTML with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276434/converting-pdf-to-html-with-python) which points to a library (poppler, which is apparently written in C++, perhaps can be accessed with JNI/JNA) and to a related question which offers even more answers.

Answer (score 1):

Only ones I know of have to be paid for.

[BFO](http://bfo.co.uk/)
[JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) from the apache foundation.