# need to convert pdf to xml or html using XSLT or through java code

Tags: java

**Hi**

I want to convert **pdf to xml or html** using xslt or through java code..please help me..Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm guessing you might be looking for a little more than <pdf>PDF file</pdf> which is still valid XML?

Comment: This is not an xslt question -- a PDF file isn't an XML file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do these conversions in XSLT because XSLT requires XML as input, and PDF is not an XML-based format.

For PDF to HTML converters in Java, see answers to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358975/is-there-any-java-library-for-converting-document-from-pdf-to-html).  And [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/converting-pdf-html-using?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+javalobby%2Ffrontpage+%28Javalobby+%2F+Java+Zone%29) recommends [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/).

There are also commercial tools around for exporting or converting PDFs as HTML or XML.