# How to show a PDF file in a Django view?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, pdf

Is it possible to show a PDF file *in* the Django view, rather than making the user have to download it to see it?

And if it is possible, how would it be done?

This is what I have so far -

```
@login_required
def resume(request, applicant_id):

    #Get the applicant's resume
    resume = File.objects.get(applicant=applicant_id)
    fsock = open(resume.location, 'r')
    response = HttpResponse(fsock, mimetype='application/pdf')

    return response
```

Answer (score 54):

Django has a class specifically for returning files, [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse). It streams files, so that you don't have to read the entire file into memory before returning it. Here you go:

```
from django.http import FileResponse, Http404

def pdf_view(request):
    try:
        return FileResponse(open('foobar.pdf', 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise Http404()
```

If you have really large files or if you're doing this a lot, a better option would probably be to serve these files outside of Django using normal server configuration.

Answer (score 38):

Simplistically, if you have a PDF file and you want to output it through a Django view, all you need to do is dump the file contents into the response and send it with the appropriate mimetype.

```
def pdf_view(request):
    with open('/path/to/my/file.pdf', 'r') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
    pdf.closed
```

You can probably just return the response directly without specifying Content-Disposition, but that better indicates your intention and also allows you specify the filename just in case the user decides to save it.

Also, note that the view above doesn't handle the scenario where the file cannot be opened or read for whatever reason. Since it's done with `with`, it won't raise any exceptions, but you still must return some sort of response. You could simply raise an `Http404` or something, though.

Comment: It doesn't work for me until i've changed  `mimetype='application/pdf`  to  `contenttype='application/pdf'`

Comment: content_type, also pdf.closed has no effect there

Comment: @azuax It's in a context processor, doesn't a return have the `__exit__` call?

Comment: It would be better to use `rb` instead of `r`, as PDF files are not text files.

Answer (score 16):

PDF files must be opened as `rb` not `r`.

```
def pdf_view(request):
    with open('/path / to /name.pdf', 'rb') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(),content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
```

Comment: Opening and showing the pdf worked for me using 'r'.

Comment: Even on non-Windows machines, it is best to use `rb` not `r`, as PDF files are not text files.

Answer (score 8):

Take out inline; if you want your file to be read from server. And also, the `HttpResponse` kwarg `mimetype` has been replaced by `content_type`:

```
(response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf')

def pdf_view(request):
    with open('/app/../Test.pdf', 'r') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(),content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
    pdf.closed
```

Answer (score 8):

Following @radtek's answer above I decided to investigate a class-based view display. I tried to use `View` but it didn't have `get_context_data()` method.

I looked [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/) for some guidance. I settled for `BaseDetailView` since I wanted to display just one object.

```
from django.http import FileResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.detail import BaseDetailView

class DisplayPdfView(BaseDetailView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        objkey = self.kwargs.get('pk', None) #1
        pdf = get_object_or_404(Pdf, pk=objkey) #2
        fname = pdf.filename() #3
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'docs\\' + fname)#4
        response = FileResponse(open(path, 'rb'), content_type="application/pdf")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = "filename={}".format(fname)
        return response
```

Commentary

1 This line accesses a named argument `pk` passed by the url calling the view.

2 This line gets the actual pdf model object.

3 I defined a method `filename(self): return os.path.basename(self.file.name)` in my model to help me get just the filename plus extension.

4 This line gets the complete filepath.

Then use file response as explained in the answers above. Also remember to use `rb` to read the pdf file

Answer (score 4):

Here is a typical use-case for displaying a PDF using class-based views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse

class DisplayPDFView(View):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  # Exec 1st
        context = {}
        # context logic here
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="worksheet_pdf.pdf"'  # Can use attachment or inline

        # pdf generation logic here
        # open an existing pdf or generate one using i.e. reportlab

        return response

# Remove login_required if view open to public
display_pdf_view = login_required(DisplayPDFView.as_view())
```

For generating your own pdf with reportlab see the [Django project Docs on PDF Generation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/outputting-pdf/).

Chris Pratt's response shows a good example of opening existing PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers aren't PDF readers (unless they have the proper plugin/addon).

You may want to render the PDF as HTML instead, which can be done [from the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276434/converting-pdf-to-html-with-python) or [the frontend](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

Comment: All the major browsers as of 2019 have native PDF support, apart from IE.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

```
import re, os
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def export_auto_doc(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name', "")
    filename = "path/to/file"+name+".pdf"
    try:
        if not re.search("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$",name):
            raise ValueError("Filename wrong format")
        elif not os.path.isfile(filename):
            raise ValueError("Filename doesn't exist")
        else:
            with open(filename, 'r') as pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename='+name+'.pdf'
                return response
            pdf.closed
    except ValueError as e:
        HttpResponse(e.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just throwing this out there.

**You can simply add your PDF resume to your static files.**

If you are using White Noise to serve your static files, then you don't even need to make the view.  Just then access your resume at the static location.

I added mine, here it is: [TIm-D_Nice.pdf](https://www.jefferythewind.com/static/main/resume/TIm-D_Nice.pdf)

**Warning: This doesn't solve the `login_required` requirement in the question**

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. This is what I ended up doing, using `{% load static %}` and a simple anchor with `href="{% url 'file.pdf' %}"`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably with an anchor in a template. For example, if you are using Django's templating engine (as most people who search for this probably are), simply serve it as a static file through an anchor.

In your template that will contain a link to the file, add at the very top

```
{% load static %}
```

Then, wherever you want to link to your pdf, put

```
<a href="{% static 'relative/path/file.pdf' %}">Click me</a>
```

The first line tells Django to look in the directories configured for static files in `settings.py`. The path that you use in the anchor tag is relative to any of the directories that you configured as static directories in `settings.py`. When you click the rendered link, it should display the PDF in your browser, provided you have your static files pathed correctly.

Comment: Oh, my bad. This doesn't exactly answer the question. This doesn't display the PDF _in_ a view...

Answer (score 0):

Use iframe url=url of pdf tag and give url of that pdf and make sure that your user will have full control of the project then pdf will be displayed on web screen

Answer (score 0):

```
def pdf_view(request,pdfSlug):
     a = Pdf.objects.get(pdf_slug=pdfSlug)
     with open(str(a.pdf_file.path), 'rb') as pdf:
         response = FileResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
         response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=a.pdf'
         return response
    pdf.closed
```

look this i'ts warked for me