# How to print out pdf file when button clicked?

Tags: python, django, file, pdf, printing

I want to print out pdf file without download it, like I have button print when I click it, my pdf file opened into new tab, where I can see my pdf file and two button like print and close. How to do it? Are there any suggestions?

Comment: You should search for more before ask!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779246/how-to-show-a-pdf-file-in-a-django-view

Answer (score 0):

Installing Acrobat Reader should let you view it in your web browser for printing.
https://get.adobe.com/reader/