# How can I make a pdf file already existed available to download by users in django?

Tags: python, django, pdf

I'm using django for a small project and I would make users able to download a pdf that's already existed in `media/doc/` path
so I wrote this code

```
    with open('media/doc/document.pdf', 'r',encoding='latin1',errors='replace') as pdf:
        response = FileResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
```

but when the pdf file get downloaded it's shown pages empty btw I have already tried utf-8 encoding and doesn't work for me even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779246/how-to-show-a-pdf-file-in-a-django-view) doesn't work for me

So How can I make pages visible?

Comment: are you sure this did point to your file `open('media/doc/document.pdf`?

Comment: @Lemayzeur yeah I'm, the file is already existed and it gets downloaded but it gives me empty pages btw I have tested many documents but I face the same issue

Comment: try sending an `HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')` with application/pdf as content_type. and remove all the arguments in open() like `with open('media/doc/document.pdf', 'rb') as pdf` .dont't for foreget `rb` for binary

Comment: @Lemayzeur it works for me Thank you I really appreciate your help

Comment: Great! I see in your comments that you have a problem of: users will download the same pdf file, do you have it work now?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are trying that should work but if it is not working than i suggest that you can download pdf file with HTML code also.

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="{{ obj.url }}" type="application/octet-stream .pdf" download="menu.pdf" target="_blank" role="button">Download a pdf file</a>
```

recently download attribute has added in HTML5 you can directly download file from HTML now no need to create extra view for that now. 
you can see details [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_download.asp)

Comment: Thank's for your help!! it works but I can't use it because not all users will download the same pdf file in fact I don't mention it above to avoid making things complicated btw the solution of @Lemayzeur works for me